# Segment Tree vs Interval Tree

Tags: computational-geometry

[Segment trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) and [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) both answer stabbing queries about line segments. In 1D, they both take $O(n \log{n})$ preprocessing time and $O(\log{n} + A)$ query time where n is the number of line segments and A is the size of the answer. Segment trees though take $O(n \log{n})$ space while interval trees only take $O(n)$ space. The question is this: what is the advantage of using a segment tree given that you need more space? I have an idea what the answer might be but I'm not sure.